# eventListener stops working after scrolling down/changing property in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a navigation bar. In it, I have some anchors. One of the anchors has the text 'Guides'. I want a div to appear when I hover over the anchor, and I want it to remain on the screen as long as I am hovering over the anchor. I also want the the div to remain on the screen as long as I am hovering over the div itself. All of this is working fine. When I scroll down, I decrease the size of the navigation bar and change the `top` position of the div. After I do this, the eventListener that I have set up to keep the div on the screen as long as I am hovering over it stops working. Please note that the div still appears when I hover over the anchor, and it remains on the screen as long as I am hovering over it.

Here's the code. The div is the one with `id="dropdown-guides"`:

```js
// Show dropdown on hovering over 'guides' in navigation bar
let guidesAnchor = document.querySelector('#nav-anchor-guides')
let guidesDropdown = document.querySelector('#dropdown-guides')

function showGuidesDropdown() {
    guidesDropdown.style.display = 'block'
}

function hideGuidesDropDown() {
    guidesDropdown.style.display = 'none'
}

guidesAnchor.addEventListener('mouseenter', showGuidesDropdown)
guidesAnchor.addEventListener('mouseleave', hideGuidesDropDown)

guidesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseenter', showGuidesDropdown)
guidesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseleave', hideGuidesDropDown)


// Show search bar on clicking search icon
let searchIcon = document.querySelector('#search-icon_anchor')
let searchBar = document.querySelector('#search-bar')

searchIcon.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (searchBar.style.display === 'none') {
        searchBar.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
        searchBar.style.display = 'none'
    }
})

// Change navigation bar on scrolling down
let navBar = document.querySelector('nav')
let mainIcon = document.querySelector('#nav-main-icon')
let navAnchors = document.querySelectorAll('nav a')
let iconDesignGuideAnchor = document.querySelector('#nav-dropdown-guides-icon-design-guide')
let pixelPerfectIconsAnchor = document.querySelector('#nav-dropdown-guides-crafting-pixel-perfect-icons')
let dribbbleAudienceAnchor = document.querySelector('#nav-dropdown-guides-build-your-dribbble-audience')

window.onscroll = () => {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 10 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 10) {
        navBar.style.height = '42px'
        navBar.style.paddingTop = '10px'
        navBar.style.boxShadow = '0px 0px 7px #0000001A'

        mainIcon.style.top = '10px'
        mainIcon.style.width = '97px'
        mainIcon.style.height = '30px'

        navAnchors.forEach(navAnchor => {
            navAnchor.style.top = '14px'
            navAnchor.style.height = '23px'
        })

        guidesDropdown.style.top = '42px'
        searchBar.style.top = '52px'

        iconDesignGuideAnchor.style.top = '65px'
        pixelPerfectIconsAnchor.style.top = '108px'
        dribbbleAudienceAnchor.style.top = '174px'
    } else {
        navBar.style.height = '80px'
        navBar.style.paddingTop = '0px'
        navBar.style.boxShadow = 'none'

        mainIcon.style.top = '18px'
        mainIcon.style.width = '139px'
        mainIcon.style.height = '43px'

        navAnchors.forEach(navAnchor => {
            navAnchor.style.top = '28px'
            navAnchor.style.height = '52px'
        })

        guidesDropdown.style.top = '80px'
        searchBar.style.top = '80px'

        iconDesignGuideAnchor.style.top = '103px'
        pixelPerfectIconsAnchor.style.top = '146px'
        dribbbleAudienceAnchor.style.top = '212px'
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#nav-main-icon {
    left: 135px;
    top: 18px;
    width: 139px;
    height: 43px;
    position: fixed;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a {
    position: fixed;
    top: 28px;
    height: 52px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666666;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #333333;
}

#nav-anchor-blog {
    left: 748px;
}

#nav-anchor-guides {
    left: 802px;
}

#nav-anchor-free-icons {
    left: 887px;
}

#nav-anchor-free-wallpapers {
    left: 979px;
}

#nav-anchor-about-me {
    left: 1110px;
}

#nav-search-icon {
    position: fixed;
    left: 1197px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 17px;
    font-size: 14px;
    fill: #00000080;
}

#nav-search-icon:hover {
    fill: #E74225;
}


.nav-dropdown {
    top: 80px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #0000001A;
    border-top: 3px solid #E74225;
    background-color: #FFFFFFFF;
    display: none;
}

#dropdown-guides {
    position: relative;
    left: 776px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 175px;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 3;
}

#dropdown-guides a {
    left: 796px;
    width: 160px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    line-height: 23px;
}

#dropdown-guides a:hover {
    background-color: #00000008;
}

#nav-dropdown-guides-icon-design-guide {
    top: 103px;
    height: 23px;
}

#nav-dropdown-guides-crafting-pixel-perfect-icons {
    top: 146px;
    height: 46px;
}

#nav-dropdown-guides-build-your-dribbble-audience {
    top: 212px;
    height: 46px;
}

#search-bar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 895px;
    width: 280px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#search-field {
    left: 915px;
    top: 103px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: hidden;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13.3333px;
    color: #757575;
}

#search-field:focus {
    outline: none;
}

h1, h3, h4, p, a {
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 500;
}

h1, h3, h4 {
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #333333;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #333333;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #666666;
}

p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 27px;
    color: #666666;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Main - Icon Utopia</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index-styles.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html"><img id="nav-main-icon" src="icon-utopia.png"></a>
                <a id="nav-anchor-blog" href="blog.html">Blog</a>
                <a id="nav-anchor-guides" href="www.iconutopia.com">Guides</a>
                <a id="nav-anchor-free-icons" href="https://iconutopia.com/free-icons/">Free Icons</a>
                <a id="nav-anchor-free-wallpapers" href="https://iconutopia.com/free-phone-wallpapers/">Free Wallpapers</a>
                <a id="nav-anchor-about-me" href="https://iconutopia.com/about/">About Me</a>
                <a id="search-icon_anchor"><svg id="nav-search-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32.2 32.2"><path d="M19 0C11.8 0 6 5.8 6 13c0 3.1 1.1 5.9 2.9 8.2l-8.6 8.6c-0.5 0.5-0.5 1.4 0 2 0.5 0.5 1.4 0.5 2 0l8.6-8.6C13.1 24.9 15.9 26 19 26c7.2 0 13-5.8 13-13S26.2 0 19 0zM19 24C12.9 24 8 19.1 8 13S12.9 2 19 2 30 6.9 30 13 25.1 24 19 24z"/></svg></a>
                <div id="dropdown-guides" class="nav-dropdown">
                    <a id="nav-dropdown-guides-icon-design-guide" href="free-icon-design-guide.html">Icon Design Guide</a>
                    <a id="nav-dropdown-guides-crafting-pixel-perfect-icons" href="crafting-pixel-perfect-icons-the-right-way.html">Crafting Pixel Perfect Icons – The Right Way!</a>
                    <a id="nav-dropdown-guides-build-your-dribbble-audience" href="build-your-dribbble-audience.html">Build your Dribbble audience</a>
                </div>
                <div id="search-bar" class="nav-dropdown">
                    <form id="search-form">
                        <input id="search-field" type="text" placeholder="Search ...">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
    <script src="nav.js"></script>
</html>
```

Please note that since the `top` set in CSS for the div is originally 80px, if I remove the code for changing the `top` of the div, after scrolling down, I can't reach it if I am hovering over the anchor, before it disappears. That's why I was not able to tell whether the eventListener stopped working because I scrolled down, or because I changed the `top` of the div.

Comment: Your `#dropdown-guides` are set to `position: relative`, where your menu is `position: fixed`. If you scroll down, your guides will remain higher up on the page (because they are relative and not fixed, like the menu), and therefor outside of the page view.

Comment: Thank you. That was a good suggestion and I applied it, but it was not ultimately what solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. In my javascript, I was setting the `height` of each `navAnchor` to fit only the text of the anchor. That's why the dropdown disappeared before I could hover over it. So I increased the height to extend the anchors to reach the bottom of the navigation bar. (I increased the height from 23px to 39px)